# cppcheck considers that variables used in macro are not used

Tags: c++, macros, static-analysis, cppcheck

For example, I have this snippet:

```
const int array_type = model.accessors[accessor_index].type;
Assert(array_type == TypeCode<T>(), "");
```

And I get this error:

```
Src/Engine/Animation/GltfLib.cpp:103:26: style: Variable 'array_type' is assigned a value that is never used. [unreadVariable]
    const int array_type = model.accessors[accessor_index].type;
```

`Assert` is a macro that was based on the regular `assert` but uses some internal logging mechanisms on top of throwing the error.

Is there a way to make cppcheck notice that the variable is actually used?

Comment: If that `Assert` macro is based on the standard library's `assert` macro, this code can, indeed, not use `array_type`. That happens when `assert` is disabled.

Comment: So to make cppcheck happy I would need to make the code available only when the Assert is enabled?

Comment: For the standard library’s `assert` macro, using `model.accessors[accessor_index].type == TypeCode<T>()` and dropping `array_type` would probably get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is telling you that: when `Assert` is disabled, you are creating a variable that is never used.

I would suggest moving the statement into the assert statement; however, you can also use the processor to remove the code when debugging is disabled.

```cpp
Assert(model.accessors[accessor_index].type == TypeCode<T>(), "");
```

If, on the other hand, you do need that line of code (perhaps because `std::map::operator[]` is non-const) then you should use `at` in the assert line and add a comment.